# Joint distribution of two random variables when a fair dice is rolled twice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am reading on joint probability distribution of random variables and working through the following example.

**Roll a die twice and Let X be the minimum value of both rolls and Y the maximum.**

The joint distribution is given as follows:

For $k, l = 1, 2....6 $,

$$
\Bbb{P}(X = k, \,Y = l) = 
\begin{cases}
0, \, \text{  if } k > l \\
\frac{1}{36}, \text{ if } k = l \\
\frac{1}{18}, \text{ if } k < l
\end{cases}
$$

I understand the first and the second case ($ k > l \text{ & } k = l $) but I'm having a hard time intuitively understanding the third case. For example $\Bbb{P}(X = 1, Y = 2)$ should be  $\frac{1}{36} $ as the pair (1, 2) occurs only once in the sample space $\Omega = \{1,...,6\}^2 $ . So why is it beign counted twice and the probability set to $\frac{1}{18}$ ?

Comment: If $k<l$ then there are two possible ways this could have come about:  $(k,l)$ or $(l,k)$., where $(a,b)$ means that the first die comes up $a$ and the second $b$.   Each has probability $\frac 1{36}$.

Comment: If the dice rolls are $A$ and $B$ then you get $\mathbb P(X = 1, Y = 2) =\mathbb P(A= 1, B = 2) +\mathbb P(A= 2, B = 1) = \frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{36}= \frac{1}{18}$.  And so on in other cases

Comment: You gave as an example that $(k, l) = (1, 2)$ results in $(X, Y) = (1, 2)$. But it is also the case that $(k, l) = (2, 1)$ results in $(X, Y) = (1, 2)$. So $\mathbb{P}(X = 1, Y = 2)$ is double the probability that $\mathbb{P}(X = 1, Y = 1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tabular representation of your joint pmf

[image]

I hope this will clarify the situation

Example: in the cell $(X;Y)=(1;2)$ that means: minimun die's value=1 and maximum die's value=2

That is $(D_1;D_2)=(1;2)$ or $(D_1;D_2)=(2;1)$